# Installation: can't boot the ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. I downloaded the `.iso` file and burned it to DVD, then I restart the system and select boot from DVD.

Now, there is just a black screen that a prompter is above the screen at the left side and I cannot write anything. After about 15 minutes my system automatically shut down.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Check your BIOS SATA Mode, it has two options: IDE Mode and AHCI Mode. IDE Mode enable you to see the disk

Hope it's helpful!